# data transfer multiple var

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a website that sells keyboards stuff and I want to transfer and display multiple options selected by a user in a text field separated with commas(,) I tried using `document.getElementById("product", "product2")` but it does not work.

Here's what I have for now.

```html
<div class="input-name">
    <label for="products">Cases: </label>
    <select name="product" id="product" class="larger" onchange="change()">
        <option selected>--Please select--</option>
            <script>productlist1()</script>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input-name">
    <label for="products">Keycaps: </label>
    <select name="product" id="product2" class="larger" onchange="change()">
        <option selected>--Please select--</option>
            <script>productlist2()</script>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="input-name">
    <label for="subject" id="subjectLabel">RE: Enquiry on</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="subject_1" readonly>
</div>
```

```js
function storeSub() {
    document.getElementById("product").selectedIndex = sessionStorage.productIndex;

    var product = document.getElementById("product").value;

    sessionStorage.subject = product;
    document.getElementById("subject").value = sessionStorage.subject;
}

function productlist1() {
    var select = document.getElementById("product");

    var options = ["Case1", "Case2", "Case3", "Case4"];

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
}

function productlist2() {
    var select = document.getElementById("product2");

    var options = ["Keycaps1", "Keycaps2", "Keycaps3", "Keycaps4"];

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
}

function change() {
    var product = document.getElementById("product").value;
    sessionStorage.product = product;
    document.getElementById("subject").value = sessionStorage.product; 
}
```

Comment: If the HTML part is clientside rendered, try not to put the script tags inside the select element ('<script>productlist*()</script>' ) since the javascript will be executed at that point before the select element is fully created?

Comment: You can attach a change event listener to the select elements inside the functions productlist1 and productlist2 that call the  change() function as soon as the something get selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a change event listener `changeSelection` to both select elements. So once anything is selected or a selection is changed, the listener will be invoked and the event is automatically passed as an argument.
Now Inside changeSelection listener, you can get the selected option by `event.target.value`.

You can use a Set to uniquely keep track of the selections. To retrieve the selections as a comma-separated string, you just need to convert the Set to an array and join it with comma.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  let select1 = document.getElementById("product");
  let options1 = ["Case1", "Case2", "Case3", "Case4"];
  
  options1.forEach(option => {
    let el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = option;
    el.value = option;
    select1.appendChild(el);
  })
  select1.addEventListener('change', changeSelection)

  let select2 = document.getElementById("product2");
  let options2 = ["Keycaps1", "Keycaps2", "Keycaps3", "Keycaps4"];
  options2.forEach(option => {
    let el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = option;
    el.value = option;
    select2.appendChild(el);
  })
  
  select2.addEventListener('change', changeSelection)

});

const selections = new Set();
function changeSelection(event){
  selections.add(event.target.value)
  let subjectInput = document.getElementById("subject");
  subjectInput.value = Array.from(selections).join(',');
}
```

```html
<div class="input-name">
  <label for="products">Cases: </label>
  <select name="product" id="product" class="larger">
      <option selected>--Please select--</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="input-name">
    <label for="products">Keycaps: </label>
    <select name="product" id="product2" class="larger">
        <option selected>--Please select--</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="input-name">
    <label for="subject" id="subjectLabel">RE: Enquiry on</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="subject_1" readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to display the output in <!div class="input-name">
    <label for="subject" id="subjectLabel">RE: Enquiry on</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="subject_1" readonly>
</div> instead of console.log , sorry i'm new to js

Comment: Of course... I updated the snippet